# CKEditor disables all jquery dialogs

Tags: ckeditor, jquery-dialog

I have a problem with ckeditor and jquery dialog window.
I have a form in which I'm dragging a div to a sortable table. When dragging I'm cloneing the div and opening a jquery dialog which contains the ckeditor.
The editor is created on the dialog's open method, and is being destroyed on close. 
After dragging the edtior for the first time it opens in the dialog, but then all the dialogs in the page are not opening.
I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'` when trying to open another dialog or drag another div with the editor.
My code is:

```
var CKEditor
$("#dialog_editor").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: $("#td_form").width(),
    modal: true,
    zIndex: -1,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Save",
            "class": 'btn btn_content',
            click: function () {
                saveEditorContent();
            }
        }
    ],
    open: function (type, data) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("#form");

        CKEditor = CKEditor = CKEDITOR.replace('text_editor', {
            extraPlugins: 'autogrow',
            removePlugins: 'resize'
        });
    },
    close: function () {
        CKEditor.destroy();
    }
});
```

I have searched all over the web, and still found no answer to that.
I tried adding the `adapters/jquery.js` and still the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was in a plugin I added to the ckeditor named "Uploadcare"

Comment: try to update uploadcare plugin, the issue was fixed quite some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to update the "Uploadcare" plugin to the current version, everything should be fine just after that.